# Add cart functionality to API or to Client?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am creating an e-commerce API using the Django Rest Framework. The API will handle the following areas:

- Databases
- User Registration
- Permissions
- Orders/Payments

There's still one area in which I'm not quite sure how to implement in my project. It's the cart functionality. Would it be better to implement it on the client-side (ex: React/Ember) or on the server-side (i.e. API)?

One scenario that confused me is if the user is logged in in different platforms (ex: Website and mobile app). I want the user to have the same cart on mulitple platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that particular use case, if you want cart persistence then it must be backend. The reason for this is one being able to have a single source of truth. The phone app and the web app cannot talk to each other unless they have some sort of "common ground" between them.

That's where the API comes in. It will allow both ends to speak to each other by having the API as the single source of truth. See my terrible diagram for a visual.

[image]

Comment: Hi Abe, could you please be more technical? How would you store cart info in the API? Would you create a Cart model and then configure it to your liking? Or is there a generally recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Well, all applications have ephemeral storage (cookies,tokens, LocalStorage, etc) and long term storage (the DB). In the case of ephemeral storage for web apps, most of those are handled on the client side (except for something like a session). Since you need to communicate across devices, you'll need to use permanent storage (the data base). For your use case, I strongly suggest extending your user model to accept an array of  sub-documents if you're going NoSQL. If you're using SQL I'd suggest a "cart" table that links products to users.